# You call it Centering, I call it Code Golf

Tags: code-golf, image-processing

*"Let's face it, aligned images are like little gifts from Heaven. Welcome, but unexpected."* - Geobits

+10000 reputation to whoever wins this challenge.

## Rules:

1) You are to generate a program.

2) Input will be an image, however whether it is passed as a file or a list of numbers is up to you.

3) Output will be a file which when opened in paint (or similar) will show the image aligned.

4) The canvas size will always be between 100 x 100 and 2000 x 2000 pixels. It will always be a rectangle, but not always a square.

5) No hard coding of images or funky URL magic.

6) No external libraries to be used.

## Guide to Centralisation (Joshpbarron Variant)

An image will be defined as centered if the 1st white(255,255,255,>0 rgba) or transparent(x,y,z,0 rgba) on an axis is equal distance (plus or minus 1 pixel) from the edge of the canvas.

This can be achieved (and will be verified by) the following method.

1) Imagine a bounding box around the object. (Black lines added for help)

[image]

2) Move the object around until the edge of the object is equal distance from the appropriate edge of the canvas.

[image]

3) Now forget the black lines.

[image]

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

More inputs [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzc0v.jpg).

And respective outputs [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zomoL.jpg).

*The +10000 rep is a lie.*

Comment: should the program handle completely white/transparent images?

Comment: As there is nothing to center, the same image should be returned. Same for images with no empty space.

Comment: You should add some specifics on the images that this should work for. For example should it work for an image that contains a mostly white background but has holes of transparency? Or does having transparency mean there will be no white, and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, but the explanation is obvious. RBGA codes are given.

Comment: In the description, you talk about the distance of the 1st white/transparent pixel from an edge. Don't you mean the first **non**-white? Otherwise all the sample inputs are already solutions, because the distance of the first white pixel from each edge is 0, so those distanced are all equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Python 3, <s>120</s> 205 bytes

**EDIT** : As the output image must have the same size as the input, the script gets longer ...

**EDIT2** : It seems that the rule 6 (no external library) has been added after I answered, so this answer is to be considered invalid anyway :(

```
from PIL.Image import*;from PIL.ImageOps import*
c='RGB';i=open(input()).convert(c);w,h=i.size
o,a=new(c,(w,h),'white'),i.crop(invert(i).getbbox())
e,f=a.size;o.paste(a,((w-e)//2,(h-f)//2));o.save('o.png')
```

The former version just cropped the input image:

```
from PIL.Image import*;from PIL.ImageOps import*
i=open(input()).convert('RGB')
i.crop(invert(i).getbbox()).save('o.png')
```

both scripts read the image file name from stdin, and saves the output image as 'o.png'. for example :

```
python3 script.py <<< s2rMqYo.png
```

It accepts at least PNG images (potentially with an alpha channel) -- Tested 'ok' on the set provided by the asker.

...waiting for my reward ):

Comment: I can't test this at the minute, but does the output canvas size match the input canvas size?

Comment: pro tip for your future shell endeavors: `python3 script.py <<< s2rMqYo.png` is cleaner

Comment: @undergroundmonorail thx !

Comment: @Joshpbarron : no it doesn't .. but it wasn't asked to be so, was it ?

Comment: All the output images are.

Comment: Would you state that keeping the same size is mandatory ?

Comment: If you must not keep the same size, then just cut all the white space, what remains is centered.

Comment: sure, that's what my answer actually does

Comment: The output must be the same size as the input, yes.

Comment: You're using a library (PIL), which is not allowed. (PIL cannot be called part of the standard libraries, because it is not included with Python by default.)

Comment: @marinus I think that this is a bit harsh.. That alienates a huge number of programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

### HTML5 + JavaScript (ES5), 515 bytes

That count includes the HTML tags as they are part of the program. If you only count the image processing code, it is **376 bytes** including the function wrapper.

```html
<canvas id=o></canvas><script>f=function(p){o=new Image();o.crossOrigin='Anonymous';o.src=p;o.onload=function(){v=document.getElementById('o'),c=v.getContext('2d');v.width=l=w=o.width;v.height=t=h=o.height;c.drawImage(o,0,0);for(k=255,d=c[g='getImageData'](0,0,w,h).data,r=b=i=0;i<d.length;)if((d[i++]<k||d[i++]<k||d[i++]<k)&&d[i++]){x=i/4%w;y=~~(i/4/w);l=l<x?l:x;t=t<y?t:y;b=b>y?b:y;r=r>x?r:x}n=c[g](l,t,r-l+1,b-t+1);c.clearRect(0,0,w,h);c.putImageData(n,(w-r+l)/2,(h-b+t)/2)}}</script><input onblur=f(this.value)>
```

#### Input

A URL to an image.

#### Security restrictions

Because this program is running in a browser environment, only URLs to [CORS-enabled images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image) will work. Imgur is CORS enabled.

[IE 10 does not support CORS.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) I haven't tested in IE 11 yet but it does work in Chrome and Firefox.

#### How to run

1. Type/paste in a URL into the input field.
2. De-focus (tab/click out of) from the input field.

#### Output

It outputs on the canvas on the page.

As this is a browser-based application, security restrictions prevent automatic download of a file but you can right click and save image in Chrome and Firefox. I haven't tested on IE 11 yet.

#### Demo

JavaScript code has been removed from the `script` element and put into the appropriate area to accommodate Stack Snippets:

```js
f = function(p) {
  o = new Image();
  o.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  o.src = p;
  o.onload = function() {
    v = document.getElementById('o'), c = v.getContext('2d');
    v.width = l = w = o.width;
    v.height = t = h = o.height;
    c.drawImage(o, 0, 0);
    for (k = 255, d = c[g = 'getImageData'](0, 0, w, h).data, r = b = i = 0; i < d.length;)
      if ((d[i++] < k || d[i++] < k || d[i++] < k) && d[i++]) {
        x = i / 4 % w;
        y = ~~(i / 4 / w);
        l = l < x ? l : x;
        t = t < y ? t : y;
        b = b > y ? b : y;
        r = r > x ? r : x
      }
    n = c[g](l, t, r - l + 1, b - t + 1);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    c.putImageData(n, (w - r + l) / 2, (h - b + t) / 2)
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id=o></canvas>
<input onblur=f(this.value)>
```

Comment: Confirmed working in Edge. I imagine it'd work in IE11 as well.

Answer (score 0):

## Processing 2 - <strike>323</strike> 450

Image is read from the file f.png in the data folder of the sketch.  Places the image and determines it's bounds.  Calculates the correct position and replaces the image shifted correctly.

```
PImage p=loadImage("h.png");int a,b,c,d,x,y,w,i,n,m,t;a=w=p.width;c=i=p.height;clear();size(w,i,P2D);x=y=b=d=t=0;image(p,0,0);loadPixels();while(x<w*i){if(pixels[x]==color(255))t=1;x++;}x=0;background(255);image(p,0,0);loadPixels();while(y*w+x<w*i){if(pixels[y*w+x]!=color(255)){if(x<a)a=x;if(x>b)b=x;if(y<c)c=y;if(y>d)d=y;}x++;if(x==w){x=0;y++;}}n=(w-(b-a))/2;m=(i-(d-c))/2;clear();if(t>0)background(255);image(p,n-a,m-c);loadPixels();save("g.png");
```

readable version:

```
PImage p=loadImage("h.png");
int a,b,c,d,x,y,w,i,n,m,t;
a=w=p.width;
c=i=p.height;
clear();
size(w,i,P2D);
x=y=b=d=t=0;
image(p,0,0);
loadPixels();
while(x<w*i)
{
 if(pixels[x]==color(255))t=1;
 x++;
}
x=0;
background(255);
image(p,0,0);
loadPixels(); 
while(y*w+x<w*i)
{
 if(pixels[y*w+x]!=color(255))
 {
   if(x<a)a=x;
   if(x>b)b=x;
   if(y<c)c=y;
   if(y>d)d=y;
 }
 x++;
 if(x==w){x=0;y++;}
}
n=(w-(b-a))/2;
m=(i-(d-c))/2;
clear();
if(t>0)background(255);
image(p,n-a,m-c);
loadPixels();
save("g.png");
```

Example output:

[image][image][image]
[image]
[image]

You can get processing [here](https://processing.org/download/)

Comment: Could you please provide a sample output file for me to compare.

Comment: It's nice...but not quite. The input images have a transparent background.

Comment: "Image is read from the file f.png". Really? In your code, I see this line: `PImage p=loadImage("h.png");` at the very top.

Comment: `color(-1)` and `background(-1)` are each 1 byte shorter than `color(255)` and `background(255)` respectively. And I think you can remove the `P2D` in the `size` call